# Tsung: BOSH over XMPP - unable to connect to opnefire server

Tags: erlang, xmpp, openfire, tsung

I have been trying to connect openfire server over bosh xmpp using Tsung. I am getting below error message saying *bad args*. I am not completely familiar with output. Could anyone help me out please?

```
**=ERROR REPORT==== 3-May-2015::13:05:08 ===
** State machine <0.133.0> terminating
** Last message in was {timeout,#Ref<0.0.0.440>,end_thinktime}
** When State == think
**      Data  == {state_rcv,none,
                     {{0,0,0,0},0},
                     undefined,0,10000,"chat.chat-auto.dev.xxx.corp",7443,
                     ts_bosh_ssl,
                     {proto_opts,negociate,"/http-bind","/chat","binary",10,
                         3,600000,infinity,infinity,32768,32768,undefined,
                         undefined,[],true,true},
                     true,1,undefined,true,undefined,
                     {1430,654707,241276},
                     7,9,false,undefined,0,[],<<>>,
                     {jabber_session,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                         undefined,undefined},
                     0,1,524288,524288,
                     [{venture,<<"xxx">>},
                      {password,
                          <<"&lt;VENTURE&gt;xxx&lt;/VENTURE&gt;&lt;TOKEN TYPE='1'&gt;&lt;PUBLIC&gt;&lt;MEMBER-ID&gt;13264037&lt;/MEMBER-ID&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;user40&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;EXPIRY-DATE&gt;1430333908891&lt;/EXPIRY-DATE&gt;&lt;/PUBLIC&gt;&lt;CIPHER-TEXT&gt;&lt;![CDATA[MNYIeugbGuJ7V1zq9nMm82JTlmiSswJM4DH2Yfg+/VpEhpIzxvG+9zYD+/wmNiRrmfCc6BX7m7+togEG4bAFsSFHTmCDRjiyKnRP0NzXZ1yiDv9M+vp6ZUwVXH9yEhpAIvL8QgsOXGpbhD7BZoC1E52O2SzsO25RQR1jbGvylWizRl0uVDHyRV/uj8DsvFtZEvb5Xc2qPvLjSJg/V5UUpLSOS6YHH9v6]]&gt;&lt;/CIPHER-TEXT&gt;&lt;/TOKEN&gt;">>},
                      {username,<<"13264037">>},
                      {tsung_userid,1}],
                     ts_jabber,[],undefined,none}
** Reason for termination =
** {badarg,[{ts_bosh,close,1,[{file,"src/tsung/ts_bosh.erl"},{line,113}]},
            {ts_client,finish_session,1,
                       [{file,"src/tsung/ts_client.erl"},{line,904}]},
            {gen_fsm,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_fsm.erl"},{line,595}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}**
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with tsung_1.5.2a-1_all.deb on 'Ubuntu trusty'.
Downgraded to tsung_1.5.1-1_all.deb, now it seems to be gone.

Comment: Still cant send bosh requests thou